# "been a watching", "been a playing" - why?

Tags: slang, dialects, contractions

I first encountered adding an "a" before a verb in songs in phrases such as "*I've been a-playing*". At first I thought that songwriters add it when they need one more syllable to make a verse sound right. Then I thought that this may be some kind of a Texas dialect or slang.

But I also saw Charles Dickens using that: "*and all mostly sounded as to be a-talking to theirselves, or a-passing blame on the t'others, and not a-talkin to us*" and I'm confused.

Why would anybody speak like that and how formal/informal is it?